# id in where clause Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to append some data into an array if it has an id of another table, however I'm getting this:

```
Undefined index: id
```

This is my code:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM users');
$rows = [];

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '" . $rows['id'] . "'");
    while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
        $rows[]['skills'] = $r2;
    }
}


print(json_encode($rows));
```

This part is where I'm having trouble at:

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '" . $rows['id'] . "'");
while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    $rows[]['skills'] = $r2;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to use `$r['id']` there, and probably the way you build the array will not result in what you want. You might consider giving your entry in `$rows` either a meaningful key (that mentioned `$r['id']`  perhaps), or build the _entire_ user _before_ adding it to `$rows`.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` <= mixing APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `$rows[] = $r` means add the value of `$r` to the end of `$rows`. So the array becomes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

)
```

If you want to access the `id` property, either use `$rows[0]['id']` or `$r['id']`.

**EDIT:**

Also note that in the code snippet you use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: OP's mixing APIs too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a different mySQL to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT `user`.*, `skills`.*
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `skills` on `users`.`id` = `skills`.`id`;
```

Here is a good examples of JOIN
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Thanks, so how can I use this in my code? Looks like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM users');

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

$sql2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '" . $r['id'] . "'");
while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    $rows[]['skills'] = $r2;
}
}


print(json_encode($rows));
```